# wait for 60 secs? What is all this?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, fastest-gun

I was just answering a question and I tried to be the first one to answer. An error came stating:

```
"Please do that after 60 seconds"
```

And, BoltClock answered first (Arggh!!)

What is this? I've never encountered it before.

Comment: At what point did you see this (as in, when you clicked the Post Answer button or ...)? On which question? What did the error look like? Off-hand, I'm not aware of any error message we send that looks like that.

Comment: @Anna: Probably this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354439/selecting-every-third-element-except-for-a-few-in-unordered-list

Answer (score 10):

You cannot post 2 answers within a minute of each other.

You had posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354472/2235132) at 2014-04-29 02:34:20 and needed to wait for a minute before you could post another answer.

This is by design perhaps to discourage people from posting the same answer to multiple questions.  It can also be argued that if a question takes a few seconds to answer, then the quality of the post is questionable.  Perhaps it doesn't merit an answer at all, or closed for whatever reason (duplicate, off-topic, ...).